Apache Camel Spring - timer not working when updating from 3.0.1 to 3.22.0
My environment:
OLD: java 11, springboot 2.5.3, camel 3.0.1
NEW: java 11, springboot 2.7.18, camel 3.22.0

I have a polling route where it process something each 10s, configures like this:
from("timer://processSomething?fixedRate=true&period=10000&synchronous=true)
.process(..)

In the old version of environment, everything works fine, but after migration of these versions (not in my control), the exchange is processing in a variety of times, I tried to up the timer to check the behaviour and for example, now, I tried to put 30s in period and it is starting each 11~17s. What could cause? Is there something different between the camel versions that i need to change the implementation?

I do not see any issue with the config. With the given config timer should run every 1 -- 11 --21 -- so on secs.
Can you post the logs where timer is running along with timestamps?
